# Receiving data from a BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been developing an app for Android who communicates with a physical piece of hardware via bluetooth. Until now we've been using normal bluetooth, but this has now changed to BLE. I am not an android developer, why this is a bit difficult for me.

At the moment I am just running a proof of concept. Whenever the physical device receives something, it transmits it back, and I can confirm this using proper BLE terminal apps. I've identified the characteristics I need to use, and I can connect to the device and send data to it. Though I cannot receive data, I am never receiving anything back.

The code shown below shows what I'm currently doing, trying to send (successfully) to the device and not so successfully receiving data. Am I totally misunderstand this concept?

Hope someone can give me a hand.

```
            @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt
                                                    gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.i("GattCallback", "connected");
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    Log.i("GattCallback", "Disconnected");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(newState);
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            byte[] newValue = characteristic.getValue();
            System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + Arrays.toString(newValue));
        }


        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

                for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gatt.getServices()) {
                    Log.i("derp", "onServicesDiscovered: service=" + gattService.getUuid());
                    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : gattService.getCharacteristics()) {
                        Log.i("derp", "onServicesDiscovered: characteristic=" + characteristic.getUuid());


                        if(characteristic.getUuid().toString().contains("9616")){
                                System.out.println("We have found the read characteristic.");
                                gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
                                BluetoothGattDescriptor desc = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("49535343-1e4d-4bd9-ba61-23c647249616"));
                                if(desc == null){
                                    System.out.println("NULL!");
                                    return;
                                }
                                desc.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                                gatt.writeDescriptor(desc);
                                System.out.println("Should be subscribed.");


                        }
                        else if(characteristic.getUuid().toString().contains("9bb3")){
                            System.out.println("Send characteristic found");

                                    characteristic.setValue("Test\n\r");
                                    boolean res = gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
                                    if(res)
                                        System.out.println("Success");


                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }

            } 
        }
```

Comment: And what is your log output? Note that you can only have one pending write operation. You need to wait for the corresponding callback before you can send a new write.

Comment: Do you intend to read the characteristic or receive the notification on that characteristic? As per your code I can see that you are trying to receive notification on specific characteristic. 

When you are using the notify property, you have to rely on the peer device to send the notification. 

Can you cross check if the peer device is properly sending the notifcation in your case?